# How to use kendotooltip on kendoMultiSelect?

Tags: kendo-multiselect

Kendotooltip is not working on kendoMultiSelect?

```
multiSelectParticipant = $("#select_multi_participant").kendoMultiSelect({
    autoBind: true,
    dataTextField: "details",
    dataValueField: "resource_id",
    filter: "contains",
    dataSource: resources,
    itemTemplate: '#= details #',
    tagTemplate: '#= resource_name #',
    select: onSelect,
    change: function (e) {
        multiParticipants = this.value();
        isMultiParticipantsChange = true;
    },
}).data("kendoMultiSelect");
$("#txtGroupCapicity").change(function () {
    groupCapicity = $("#txtGroupCapicity").val();
    $("#select_multi").data("kendoMultiSelect").options.maxSelectedItems = (groupCapicity - 1);
});

function onSelect(e) {
    resourceTooltip = e.sender.wrapper.kendoTooltip({
    position: "top",
    content: e.item.text(),
    autoHide: true,
    width: 250,
    height: 20,
    animation: {
        duration: 0
    }
  }
 );
}
```

Comment: When you say it "is not working", *how* is it not working.  Please describe what happens.  Do you get any error messages?  Is there any logged output?

Comment: We added tagTemplate, showtooltip functin and  gappointmentTooltip variable like  tagTemplate: '<span onmouseover="showtooltip(\'#=details#\')">#=resource_name#</span>',//'#= resource_name #', //'<span style="display:block;" title="#=details#">#=resource_name#</span>'
gappointmentTooltip = $("#select_multi_participant_taglist").kendoTooltip({
        filter: "li", position: "top", content: "", animation: { duration: 0} });});
function showtooltip(e) {
        gappointmentTooltip.data("kendoTooltip").options.content = e;
        gappointmentTooltip.data("kendoTooltip").refresh();
}